How to setup API key for nasdaq data link library in python?
The documentation says that the local file is ~/.nasdaq/data_link_apikey but I can't find it anywhere. How can I authenticate using the API key?

You have to create that file yourself.

@Barmar I did that and put the API key in that file with that file name. But it still doesn't work. Do I have to use a specific format for the file(like txt or py)? Also, do I just put the key as it is in the file and nothing else?

It should just be a plain text file, no special format. You put it in your .nasdaq subdirectory like it says?

@Barmar There is no nasdaq subdirectory already there. Do I also have to make that as well?

Yes, of course. That's where it's looking for the file.

@Barmar Gotcha. I’ll give that a try.

@Barmar I tried that and it still doesn't work. Do you have any idea what might be wrong. I made a folder called "nasdaq" and inside of I put a file named "data_link_apikey" with the just the key in the file. I didn't put any extension to the file but I think a file like this is just read a txt file.

The folder has to be named .nasdaq -- the . at the beginning is important.

@Barmar I can't start a folder name with a "." in macos. I just used the readkey function of the library to authenticate and now it is working.

Why not? In Terminal: mkdir .nasdaq

Then echo 'this is my API key' > .nasdaq/data_link_apikey
